# Font size changed when email is sent

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am facing the following issue: when I send out a automated email the font size changes from 10 to 11. See below the code I am using:

```
With OutlookMailitem
            .To = toEmail
            .CC = ccEmail & ";" & ccEmail2 & ";" & ccEmail3
            .Subject = "Submit your Timesheet"
            .HTMLbody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & "Hey " & toName & "," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "We noticed your timesheet is still open. Please submit your timesheet each Monday before 12PM. If you face any issues, do let us know." & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "Best," & signature
            .Send
        End With
```

Any idea what is causing this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using px.

```
<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13px'>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work...

Comment: Also, I found that you did not close your <p> tag. could you check this, please?

Comment: What should I add to close it properly?

Comment: `</p>` will close the p tag

Comment: Could you please indicate where I should put this in the following line?

```
.HTMLbody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & "Hey " & toName & "," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "We noticed your timesheet is still open. Please submit your timesheet each Monday before 12PM. If you face any issues, do let us know." & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "Best," & signature
```

Comment: HTMLbody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & "Hey " & toName & "," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "We noticed your timesheet is still open. Please submit your timesheet each Monday before 12PM. If you face any issues, do let us know." & "</p>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "Best," & signature

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add `"px"` or the unit that you want before the font-size, if this doesn't work... maybe another function is overwriting your styles, then try to add !important after the `font-size: 13px` like this:

```
<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13px!important;'>
```

*!important shall take priority over any other style that is applied.*

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work...

Comment: @db2020 you could check with the browser inspector which styles are being applied on the email?

Comment: Hey Ginés, what do you mean with browser inspector? Relatively new to working with html :) I've done this all in VBA.